# Installing GPU R packages on Ubuntu

Tags: r, gpu

I am trying to install R GPU package "gpuR" and I get the following error message:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'gpuR.so' failed
make: *** [gpuR.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘gpuR’
* removing ‘/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gpuR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gpuR’ had non-zero exit status

When I try to install OpenCL, I get the following error message:

> install.packages("OpenCL")
>   Installing package into ‘/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/OpenCL_0.1-3.tar.gz'
>
> ## Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 15524 bytes (15 KB)

downloaded 15 KB

- installing *source* package ‘OpenCL’ ...
  ** package ‘OpenCL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ocl.c -o ocl.o
  ocl.c:6:23: fatal error: CL/opencl.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'ocl.o' failed
  make: *** [ocl.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘OpenCL’
- removing ‘/home/fibrou/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/OpenCL’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenCL’ had non-zero exit status

I am running the latest LTS version of Ubuntu: 16.04, as well as the latest version of RStudio (Version 1.1.383 ) and R (R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree") I can find.

Why am I not able to install the GPU packages?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try following the instructions at [the gpuR wiki](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-Linux)? It notes the dependencies needed ("OpenCL headers (can be found at Khronos.org), An OpenCL SDK specific to your GPU vender (AMD, NVIDIA, Intel, etc.), [and] A compiler that supports C++11 (e.g. template aliases)") and how to get them.

Comment: I did not, but after additional dependency manual installs (I thought they would be done automatically) I was finally able to get it installed. gpuR also recognizes the correct make and model of my GPU too, so I think I installed correctly...

Comment: Glad to hear everything worked out. I also run Ubuntu (MATE), and I find a lot of advantages for working on a computer running a Linux operating system, but one thing you'll always need to look out for is that when R packages have system dependencies (rather than R package dependencies), you'll have to install them yourself. Many packages nowadays will print informative error messages telling you which system dependencies to install, but not all of them.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'm trying to install MXNet, and boy-oh-boy, system dependencies all over the place.  I'm running into a couple of errors too - but that's for another entry...

Thanks for all the help

Comment: @fibrou unfortunately the dependencies cannot be manually installed given the proprietary nature of the hardware.  There are some possible open-source OpenCL backends but they also have dependencies.  It was therefore decided to leave it to the user to know the hardware they are interested in using.  I have tried to make the installation as simple as possible.  Any suggestions or contributions are welcome.